# Automatic scxml code synthesis for statechart models

Tags: statechart, scxml

Can the [w3c scxml specs](http://www.w3.org/TR/scxml/) be considered under model driven development? i.e statecharts as models for scxml which can be autogenerated using a tool instead of hand coding them. I'm looking for such a tool for tablet GUI interactions.

David Harel's tools generated c/c++ code from statechart of system behavior. IBM Statemate(ilogix Statemate Magnum) for hardware statecharts and IBM Rhapsody for embedded software statecharts.

Answer (score 5):

This might be a good fit: https://github.com/jbeard4/SCION

It's an SCXML implementation in JavaScript. It can be used for Web UI development (this was its original purpose), or embedded in many other programming languages/runtimes.

Disclaimer: I am the author.

Answer (score 0):

You can try QT state chart editor where you can design state and can add custom java script code. QT framework has state chart execution engine through whic you can run your state chart in c++ application without any specific code for state charts/model.

I am looking alternative of same tool but for c# integration.

http://doc.qt.nokia.com/4.7-snapshot/statemachine-api.html